# Duplicating a Data Extension using ExactTarget SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am trying to figure out how to duplicate an existing Data Extension. That is, for a defined Data Extension, I want to duplicate it, along with the columns and the data in it.

Here's what I think I need to do. For a given Data Extension, we:

1. Retrieve fields in the Data Extension using `DataExtensionField` object
2. Use `DataExtensionFieldType` object to get the field type (Text, Number, Boolean, etc) of each field returned from step 1
3. Retieve records from Data Extension in step 1 using `DataExtensionObject` object
4. Create new Data Extension using `DataExtensionFromAPI` setting the columns and field types from steps 1 and 2
5. Add data from step 3 to new `DataExtensionObject`

Can someone confirm if this is actually correct? From following the documentation, the issue with this proposed approach is that there does not seem to be a method to retrieve Data Extension field types. According to the documentation, there are no methods supported for the [DataExtensionFieldType Object](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/dataextensionfieldtype/).

I'm at a bit of a loss here how to approach this seemingly straightforward task...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super close -

Step 1 will retrieve the fields and field types togethers like this:

```
 <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Header>
      <ns1:fueloauth xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com">xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ns1:fueloauth>
   </Header>
   <Body>
   <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
         <ObjectType>DataExtensionField</ObjectType>
         <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
         <Properties>Name</Properties>
         <Properties>FieldType</Properties>
         <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
            <Property>DataExtension.CustomerKey</Property>
            <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
            <Value>myDEKey</Value>
         </Filter>
      </RetrieveRequest>
   </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

The rest of your steps look correct.